# tcl/tk widget command and bind mouse button click conflict

Tags: tcl, bind

I can't get event from a widget stop propagating to parent window. I mean I have a spinbox with its own command, and I got toplevel bind on mouse click to exit the application

```
spinbox .mask -command { remask this %d ; break }
bind . <ButtonRelease-1> { recopy this ; exit }
```

When I click on the spinbox scroll button, the application exits all the time. the break doesn't seem to work within spinbox event command.

Also Up and Down key binding don't work also.

Here is the complete code for convenience

```
proc expand { name } {
    upvar 2 $name what
    uplevel "upvar 1 $name that"
    foreach key [array names what] {
      uplevel "upvar 0 that($key) $key"
    }
}

proc remask { name { delta 0 } } {
  expand $name

  if {$delta == "up"  } { set delta  1 }
  if {$delta == "down"} { set delta -1 }
  set delta [expr $delta < 0 ? -1 : $delta > 0 ? 1 : 0]
  set date [clock add $date $delta $unit]
  set file [clock format $date -format $mask -locale fr]
  set test [file exists $file]
}

proc reunit { name } {
  expand $name

  set map {
    %a days
    %A days
    %d days
    %V weeks
    %b months
    %B months
    %m months
    %y years
    %Y years
    %g years
    %G years
  }

  foreach {key value} $map {
    if { [string first $key $mask] > 0 } {
      set unit $value
      break
    }
  }
}

proc recopy { name } {
    expand $name

    if {!$test} {
        if [file exists $mask] {
            file copy $mask $file
        } else {
            open $file w
        }
    }
}

array set map {
    0   green
    1   red
}

set taken 0
if {$argc > 1} {
  set path [lindex $argv 0]
  cd [file dirname $path]
} else {
  set path "file_%Y%m%d.txt"
}
set this(mask)  [file tail $path]
set this(file)  $this(mask)
set this(date)  [clock seconds]
set this(unit)  days
set this(test)  [file exists $this(file)]

reunit this
remask this

set posx [winfo pointerx .]
set posy [winfo pointery .]
set posx [expr $posx - 50]
set posy [expr $posy - 40]

wm title . "rename $this(mask)"
wm attributes . -toolwindow true
wm geometry . +$posx+$posy

spinbox .mask -textvariable this(file) -foreground $map($this(test)) -command { remask this %d ; break }
pack .mask -fill x -padx 20 -pady 5

grab .
bind . <ButtonRelease-1> { recopy this ; exit }
bind . <Key-Return>      { recopy this ; exit }
bind . <ButtonRelease-3> { exit }
bind . <Key-Escape>      { exit }
bind . <MouseWheel>      { remask this %D ; .mask configure -foreground $map($this(test)) }
bind . <Key-plus>        { remask this +1 ; .mask configure -foreground $map($this(test)) }
bind . <Key-Up>          { remask this +1 ; .mask configure -foreground $map($this(test)) }
bind . <Key-minus>       { remask this -1 ; .mask configure -foreground $map($this(test)) }
bind . <Key-Down>        { remask this -1 ; .mask configure -foreground $map($this(test)) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core issue is that `break` is only magical in a binding script, and not in the `-command` option script, as that is something that is only invoked indirectly from a binding script (via a class-level binding). That's not about to change. (Also, the `-command` option also doesn't do `%`-bind-substitutions normally, though it might substitute; see the widget documentation.)

To prevent that widget from propagating the `<ButtonRelease-1>` event (*and just that event*) to the containing toplevel, you need to insert an extra [binding tag](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/bindtags.htm) and apply the binding there.

```
spinbox .mask -command { remask this %d }
bind . <ButtonRelease-1> { recopy this ; exit }
bindtags .mask {.mask Spinbox extraMagic.mask . all}
bind extraMagic.mask <ButtonRelease-1> break
```

The binding tag string `extraMagic.mask` is not special *at all* except that it is mentioned in both the `bind` and the `bindtags` commands. (I put the name of the widget at the end because I'm thinking in terms of having this applied to a single widget only.) What is special is that it comes between `Spinbox` (the class binding tag) and `.` (the toplevel binding tag) and that it has a binding for `<ButtonRelease-1>` which does a `break`.

Note that this will only apply to events delivered to that specific spinbox; a click on any other widget in the toplevel will make things exit. (It's usually recommended to only put accelerator key-bindings on toplevels, and for user code to avoid attaching to `all` at all as global bindings are very subtle things that apply in places that it is easy to forget.)

Comment: perfect your explanation is clear, more than the documentation. thanks to you I do understand the bindtags stuff now.

Comment: I forget where the canonical explanation for the bindtags stuff is; it might even be in a book…